# GDB skipping behavior

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, visual-studio-debugging

Coming from debugging C# in Visual Studio to GDB, I notice that when stepping over after settings breakpoints, GDB "jumps over" over closing braces of blocks, else blocks, or other code. Whereas Visual Studio went through the complete path, enabling to see "everything that was happening".

For example, if I write:

```
if (1) {
    int a = 0;
}
else {
    int b = 0;
}
```

In Visual Studio/C#, the debugger will go through lines 1, 2, 3, 4 and finally 6, then move on.

In GDB/C, the debugger will go through 1, 2, then skip lines 3, 4 and 6, and move on to the rest of the code.

I tried to look into disabling optimization, or range-stepping, but those seem not related in this behaviour.

This is how I am compiling my program:

```
gcc -g -O0 src/main.c src/parser.c -o bin/masc
```

Am I observing something inherent to GDB (or Visual Studio)? Is there an option to change this behavior in GDB?

Comment: What commands are you executing in `gdb`? Have you tried [`breakpoints`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Breakpoints.html)?

Comment: @Sergio Yes, I've expanded the question to include this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no change from line 3-7. Jumps by C# debugger are redundant. `gcc` jumps directly to the line of next change.